# how to avoid "wrong number of arguments" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code in my controller

```
  def create
    @employees = Group.find(params[:employee][:group_id]).employees
    puts "count!!!!" + @employees.count.to_s
    Communicate.deliver_message(params[:subject],@employees,params[:body].to_s)
    flash[:notice] = "your message has been sent"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

following code in `Communicate` model:

```
  def message(sub, people, msg)
    #puts "employee count!!!" + people.count
    subject    sub
    bcc        "my_email.s@gmail.com"
    from       'my_email.s@gmail.com'
    sent_on    Time.now

    body       :greeting => msg
  end
```

Error I am getting is "wrong number of arguments" on 3rd line of the `create` method.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but... `Communicate.deliver_message`, `Communicate.message`... Which one is it?

Comment: Does Communicate inherit off ActionMailer::Base ?

Comment: sorry this was a typo on my part. I was able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

if it did inherit from ActionMailer::Base, then the problem is the name of the method: "message" is used inside ActionMailer. Need to change the method name.